# c++ callback from win32 event hook

Tags: c++, lambda, win32gui

I am trying to write my own boilerplate code/library-stuff for window creation and management. What I am trying to achieve, is that a programmer is able to call a function with a lambda param, which then will be executed on window close. (Like the way JavaScript JQuery enables programmers to add event handlers.) The structure I am trying to create is something like:

- I have an object `window` of my custom `Window` class, which holds information about a particular window.
- This object sets an event hook for its window with `SetWinEventHook(...)`.
- The programmer calls `window.close(lambda)`, which adds a lambda function to the window's close event handler list/`vector`.
- When a close event occurs, this hook calls the callbacks from the window's close event list.

I have been searching for a while now on the interwebs, but I could not find any way to perform the last step. I can add a hook to the event, sure, but then this hook must be static, or must be a lambda without captures, so there is no way to communicate with the window object? I guess this means it is a stupid idea, but is there any way to still implement this in a kind-of-decent way?

Comment: Call SetWinEventHook() only once.  The callback provides the window handle.  So you need a static `map<HWND, Window*>` to find your Window object back.

Comment: I might have not been entirely clear about that, but I indeed call SetWinEventHook only once. About the map, that indeed a splendid idea! Can you please make a complete answer from that? Then I can mark it as "answered my question." ;)

Comment: No idea how to make it "complete".  Just show us what you did in your own post and mark it as the answer to close your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans pointed out, using a map to get a window for each window handle works great. I have a (static) map with window handlers and windows:

```
map<HWND, Window *> Window::handlerWindows;
```

The handler of a window can be fetched via a static getter:

```
Window *Window::getWindow(HWND handler) {
    return handlerWindows[handler];
}
```

The window procedure uses this method to get a window for a window handle, to make it handle an event:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK windowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    Window *window = Window::getWindow(hwnd);
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            window->handle(msg);
...
```

To add a handler, a lambda is provided alongside an event constant, like:

```
window->bind(WM_CLOSE, [&run](){
    run = false;
    return true;
});
```

This adds the handler to the event handlers list:

```
map<DWORD, vector<function<bool()>>> eventHandlers;
```

and

```
void Window::bind(DWORD event, function<bool ()> handler) {
    eventHandlers[event].push_back(handler);
}
```

And then the events are handled with:

```
void Window::handle(DWORD event) {
    vector<function<bool ()>> handlers = eventHandlers[event];
    for_each(handlers.begin(), handlers.end(), [](function<bool ()> handler){
        handler();
    });
}
```

This works quite well.